# Пропарсить переменную в шаблоне django

Tags: переменные, синтаксический-анализ, шаблонизаторы, django

Здравствуйте!

Есть django шаблон:

```
{% block content %}
    <article>
        {{ text.article|safe }}
    </article>
{% endblock %}
```

Переменная `text.article` содержит html код статьи. Так же в `text.article` могут встречаться некоторые django теги.

Вопрос такой: можно ли (как?) на месте (в шаблоне, а не во вьюхе) пропарсить эту переменную?

И еще вопрос: из соображений безопасности я хочу при парсинге переменной `text.article` дать доступ только к определенным тегам. К примеру, только к тегам `{% playlist %}` и `{% url %}`. Как такое устроить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Чем, например?

У Вас где-то просчет в архитектуре. Даже переменная "text.article" на это указывает.

Вся логика должна быть во view, а в шаблоне только подстановка значений. Я могу понять html в переменной - например, разметка текста, но как туда попали "django теги"?

Подумайте над архитектурой. Лучше день потерять, потом за пять минут долететь :)

Comment: "text.article" — это html код статьи. Он хранится в бд, его пишут админы через wysiwyg редактор. В статью также могут быть добавлены динамические элементы. К примеру тег {% playlist "name" %} добавляет музыку, а тег {% userprofile "name" %} — ссылку на профиль пользователя. Готовый html вместо тегов вставлять не вариант, так как со временем плейлисты и профили пользователей меняются ну и все такое. Если не django тегами, то как добавлять это все?

Comment: Ну, обычно делают article.text, article.datetime, article.user, но не об этом речь..

Тут надо отделить мух от котлет и попробовать использовать не template tags, а что-то иное.

На данный момент вижу такой вариант: придумываем свой "тег", например, как в ВК, [username|1114] и [playlist|28419], где слово - идентификатор типа объекта, а число - его id, и парсим эти теги с помощью js (куда без него в наше время?). В результате чего меняем [username|1114] на <a href="/user/1114/">username</a>, а плейлист тянем через AJaX.

Comment: Тогда проще сразу обойтись без тегов и парсинга: в редакторе создаем <div class="playlist" playlistId="28419"></div> и тянем его через ajax чем-нибудь типа .each().

Comment: > Ну, обычно делают article.text, article.datetime, article.user

Так и сделано, просто тут путаница с именами небольшая. =)

Comment: И в этот момент из-за горизонта выплывает еще одна мягкая часть тела - js-плееры не видят треки, загруженные через ajax, приходится их убивать и заново биндить :)

hlml5 audio тоже не поможет - mp3 понимают полторы калеки.

Comment: Не вижу проблем... Я же аяксом загружу только ссылки на файлы, а грузить их плеер сам будет. Ладно, завтра попробую, если будут проблемы — вынесу в отдельный вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Напишите [template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/), который принимает html и контекст, и рендерит одно с другим. По второму пункту надо смотреть исходники шаблонизатора, если не получится - всегда можно регулярками отфильтровывать "хорошие" тэги.

Comment: Ну это все можно и во вьюхе сделать. Или фильтр написать... Все-таки напрягает меня такое решение чем-то...

Comment: Чем, например?

Comment: Например тем, что шаблонизатор прийдется запускать несколько раз. Да и вообще код станет толстым и неуклюжим. Хотя вариант с фильтром накрайняк пойдет.